# In Django-rest-frame work 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here i have using abstract concept but when i try to call product it was throwing Error like `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'`.

In this models.py Product is the main model and other models like Category, Reviews, Specification and ItemNumber are sub models. In Product all Other sub models are  mentioned as array field.

I don't know how to over come this so please tell me how to achieve this.

**Models.py**

```
class Categories(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
class CategoriesForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Categories
       fields = ['name']
class Specifications(models.Model):
   cost_price = models.FloatField()
   quantity = models.IntegerField()
   sell_price = models.FloatField()
   size = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True


class SpecificationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Specifications
       fields = ['cost_price', 'quantity', 'sell_price', 'size']


class Reviews(models.Model):
   author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   rating = models.FloatField()
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   class Meta:
       abstract = True
class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Reviews
       fields = ['author', 'date', 'rating', 'comment']

class ItemNumber(models.Model):
  spec_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class ItemNumberForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = ItemNumber
    fields = ['spec_id']
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True)
   categories = models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=Categories,
       model_form_class=CategoriesForm
   )
   specifications = models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=Specifications,
       model_form_class=SpecificationsForm
   )
   description = models.TextField()
   reviews = models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=Reviews,
       model_form_class=ReviewsForm
   )
   drizzly = models.BooleanField()
   complete = models.BooleanField()
   comment = models.TextField()
   item_number = models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=ItemNumber,
       model_form_class=ItemNumberForm
   )
   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class Productserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback. Furthermore it makes more sense to specify the exact `attname`, since without it, it is rather hard to know what is going on.

Comment: There is also something rather weird: you make a `ModelForm` on an *abstract* `Model`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes.

Comment: do you understand what an *abstract* model is? That means that you only use for other models that inherit from it, there is no table related to the model, nor can you really *create* such object.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: make the models *non*-abstract.

I think you do not really grasp the concept of an *abstract* model. An abstract model means that it does not really exists: you define columns, but there is no table for that model. You only do that such that can make another model that *inherits* from the abstract model(s), such that you automatically can define a huge amount of columns, as well as certain common behavior. Or as specified in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some **common
>   information into a number of other models**. You write your base class
>   and put `abstract=True` in the `Meta` class. This model will then **not be
>   used to create any database table**. Instead, when it is used as a base
>   class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child
>   class.

Here however you define forms, serializers, etc. on these abstract models. This is *very* strange, since how would that `CategoriesForm` manage to create a `Categories` object, if you - by design - should not be able to construct such `Categories` objects: you can only construct *non*-abstract model objects (that might, or might not inherit from one or more abstract models).

Your models, are defined as abstact:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

So you should omit this (and this is probably applicable to most, if not all, models you defined).

You then will also have to construct the table in the database. You can do this by making migrations:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

and then migrate the database:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

The error als shows up if we make an abstract model, and create an object, like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then if we construct such object, we get the same error:

```
>>> Foo(bar=12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 513, in __repr__
return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
File "/tmp/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 516, in __str__
return '%s object (%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)
File "/tmp/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 564, in _get_pk_val
return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

> **Note**: the *nomenclature* does not really follows the guidelines. Normally the name of a model is *singular*, so `Category` instead of <s>`Categories`</s>, and `CategoryForm` instead of <s>`CategoriesForm`</s>, or <s>`CategoryForms`</s>.